# How can I convert UTM coordinates from Meters to Feet?

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, map-projections, proj4js, utm

Does anyone have a formula or conversion that will switch my UTM coordinates from Meters to Feet?  I found Javascript code that will convert UTM coords in meters to Lat/Long but I will need my UTM in feet before I convert it to Lat/Long.

Comment: You are just looking for a formula for converting metres to feet? 1 metre = 3.280839895 feet. Just curious, if you have UTM in metres and a routine to convert that to lat/lon, why do you need UTM in feet? (I'm pretty sure UTM is defined as being in metres not feet, so in feet it's not really UTM)

Comment: Good God.. I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks Lazarus.  Can you post that response to the answers so I can give you credit? thanks

Comment: I've added it but just glad to help. I've spent many, many hours staring at problem only to have someone else point to the issue without really even reading the code. Some times we can be just too close to the problem space :)

Comment: Sounds like there's something unorthodox with your UTM conversion code if it needs feet (UTM by definition uses metres). An alternative for the transform is to simply use the Proj4JS JavaScript library. Open Source + supports a number of different projections,etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just looking for a formula for converting metres to feet? 1 metre = 3.280839895 feet.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, 1 inch is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch#International_inch) to be 25.4 mm, and 1 foot is exactly 12 inches, so 1 foot is exactly 0.3048 m.

Hence 1 m is 1/0.3048 feet, or 3.280839895013123359580052493438320209973753... feet.

Answer (score 0):

Use [google](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=1+metre+in+feet&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) to compute these things quickly.